# Why is the mutual friends count different?

Tags: facebook

When I put my cursor and hover it on the name under "People You May Know" column, why does it say “105 Mutual Friends” in the box but only “80 Mutual Friends” in the outside?

What is it trying to hide?

[image: Screenshot]

Notice how it says “105 Mutual Friends” in the hovered box but it says only 80 in the “People You May Know” box.

Answer (score -1):

I guess this is because both your friends (i.e., the friend's profile you are in and the mutual friend) have not shown their complete friend's list to you.

Comment: How do you mean? The question only refers to one person (who isn't a FB-friend of @oneNonlu).